# Tool for a "meta cloud"

Tags: cloud, dropbox

Is there a tool in Ubuntu which collects the different logins of my cloud hosts (dropbox, ubuntu one, box.net, HIdrive etc...) and turns them into a big "meta cloud virtual hard disk"?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such a tool. You could probably implement one, along these lines :-

- Since cloud hosts tend to transfer whole files, split storage into many smaller blocks
- Each block file forms 1 LVM physical volume
- Aggregate the block files into logical volumes

It's important, of course, that you only mount the volumes from one client at a time - and it's probably safest if you only use 1 client, conflicts will inevitably cause horrible filesystem corruption.